# Why are .innerHTML problems not an issue when using JQuery().html()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, innerhtml

I worked out any single instance of `document.getElementById("MyID").innerHTML = "A value"` in [this](http://www.proglogic.com/code/javascript/time/worldclock.php) Javascript World Clock guide causes Wordpress Admin not to load completely and breaks various areas of the Wordpress admin interface.

I solved it by replacing each instance with `jQuery("#MyID").html("A value"))` which appears to work fine. What is causing `.innerHTML` to fail miserably but not `JQuery().html()`?

Comment: I don't think it does, if I recall correctly they both reset the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely the pertinent part of the jQuery source:

```
try {
    for ( var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++ ) {
        // Remove element nodes and prevent memory leaks
        if ( this[i].nodeType === 1 ) {
            jQuery.cleanData( this[i].getElementsByTagName("*") );
            this[i].innerHTML = value;
        }
    }

    // If using innerHTML throws an exception, use the fallback method
} catch(e) {
    this.empty().append( value );
}
```

Note that it handles exceptions thrown.

[See it for yourself in 1.5.2](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js).

Comment: I'm marking this is as my accepted answer. That doesn't mean I know exactly why it works but its clear JQuery is doing a more thorough job with error checking.

Answer (score 3):

At a guess I would suspect either browser-specific stuff or `document.getElementById("MyID")` returns null, causing an exception.

Comment: If `document.getElementByID("MyID")` returns null, then `jQuery("#MyID")` should return an empty jQuery object, so the `.html()` call wouldn't do anything.

Comment: @justkt not doing anything is different from throwing an exception if there was stuff after the call.

Comment: right, but the question seems to indicate that the DOM *is* changed by `.html()`.

Comment: @justkt "solved it by replacing each instance" implies that one or more of them may have been broken, although it isn't clear.

Comment: No I didn't see any errors in the original `.innerHTML` code. I actually have just three clocks with identical syntax apart from the values I passed to the functions. It was only when I commented out all references to `innerHTML` that the errors were resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This is how jQuery does it:

```
html: function( value ) {
    if ( value === undefined ) {
        return this[0] && this[0].nodeType === 1 ?
            this[0].innerHTML.replace(rinlinejQuery, "") :
            null;

    // See if we can take a shortcut and just use innerHTML
    } else if ( typeof value === "string" && !rnocache.test( value ) &&
        (jQuery.support.leadingWhitespace || !rleadingWhitespace.test( value )) &&
        !wrapMap[ (rtagName.exec( value ) || ["", ""])[1].toLowerCase() ] ) {

        value = value.replace(rxhtmlTag, "<$1></$2>");

        try {
            for ( var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++ ) {
                // Remove element nodes and prevent memory leaks
                if ( this[i].nodeType === 1 ) {
                    jQuery.cleanData( this[i].getElementsByTagName("*") );
                    this[i].innerHTML = value;
                }
            }

        // If using innerHTML throws an exception, use the fallback method
        } catch(e) {
            this.empty().append( value );
        }

    } else if ( jQuery.isFunction( value ) ) {
        this.each(function(i){
            var self = jQuery( this );

            self.html( value.call(this, i, self.html()) );
        });

    } else {
        this.empty().append( value );
    }

    return this;
},
```

Comment: And how does dumping the source code for the `html()` method answer the question?

Comment: Sorry but I agree with @BoltClock, this is just pointing me to what I'm already using. You would have to explain *why* this works to answer my question.

Comment: @edwinbradford: I don't understand how this *can not* be helpful. You are wondering **why** `html()` works and not `innerHTML=""`. What I posted above is exactly how jQuery does its `html` method. If you can not deduct to why this works the way it does, you should not have marked the other post that shows (only part of) what the method does either.

Comment: I think it is because the other answer makes note of how jQuery is catching exceptions and if so, using a fall-back. It is also only showing the part of the code relevant to the explanation.

Comment: Thank you John, John's reply summarizes my reasoning very well. Thanks also to you @Shaz for submitting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

About the only difference between what you tried and what jQuery's html method **might** be doing is removing the content of the element before inserting the new content. So try removing the content first and if you are only inserting plain text, create and insert a text node instead of setting the innerHTML.

So:

```
function replaceContent(id, s) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  if (el) {
    while (el.firstChild) {
      el.removeChild(el.firstChild);
    }
    el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(s));
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I wondered about this. The element being referenced was empty, I tried changing it from a `<div>` to a `<span>` and also tried a `<p>` in case it preferred text elements but it made no difference.